# Hadoop with C# / .NET

Tags: hadoop

I found that Hadoop can be used with C# ([Hadoop for .NET Developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/data_otaku/archive/2013/08/14/hadoop-for-net-developers.aspx)) but how mature is this support? Can I use it in production or better go with some JVM language?

Comment: I suggest to go with `java` or `python` for Hadoop will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hadoop streaming jar to achieve this . Also Microsoft .NET Map Reduce API For Hadoop should be used to write programs in c#.

All the below code is from below [post](https://martin.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27328520), it also has clear steps to build and execute.

```
using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HadoopExploration
{
    class WordCount
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Usage: WordCount <input path> <output folder>");
            }
            HadoopJobConfiguration jobConfig = new HadoopJobConfiguration()
            {
                InputPath = args[0],
                OutputFolder = args[1],
                DeleteOutputFolder = true
            };
            Hadoop.Connect().MapReduceJob.Execute<WordMapper, SumReducer>(jobConfig);
        }
    }
}
using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace HadoopExploration
    {
        public class WordMapper : MapperBase
        {
            public override void Map(string inputLine, MapperContext context)
            {
                char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
                //split up the passed in line
                string[] individualWords = inputLine.Trim().Split(delimiterChars);
                //write output KVP for each one of these
                foreach (string word in individualWords)
                {
                    context.EmitKeyValue(word.ToLower(), "1");
                }
            }
        }
    }

using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HadoopExploration
{
    public class SumReducer : ReducerCombinerBase
    {
        public override void Reduce(string key, IEnumerable<string> values, ReducerCombinerContext context)
        {
            int wordCount = 0;
            //iterate through the count values passed to us by the mapper
            foreach (string countAsString in values)
            {
                wordCount += Int32.Parse(countAsString);
            }
            //write output "answer" as a KVP
            context.EmitKeyValue(key, Convert.ToString(wordCount));
        }
    }
}
```